# How to Redirect URL Page to another URL

Tags: windows, router, redirect

Good Day, When a user enters http://test.com on the browser I would like him redirected to my site published on our server. I already knew that I can change it in the hosts file of devices connected to the network but it will takes a lot of time so I'm thinking if I can change it on the router.

Can you give me a link or instructions that could help me regarding the scenario / how to do this on my router? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about configure DNS for `test.com` to make it points to your server's IP ?

Comment: @krisFR I don't have an access to test.com. that's why I'm thinking if i can configure it on the user's network router.

Answer (score 0):

The old school way to do this is via HTML meta refresh.

```
# Redirect to http://example.com/ immediately: 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

Have a look at these docs for further reading :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

Comment: Thanks mate! gonna read it first. Will accept your answer after testing. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting you have redirect methods available in almost every web programming language. For example php.

header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php